# How to use currency pipe with ngx-translate?

Tags: angular, localization, angular-pipe, ngx-translate, currency-pipe

I am using ngx-translate for the internalization of my angular application. I have added a dropdown that has 3 languages(fr, de and en). On language switching, I want to change the currency symbol. I have added a custom pipe also but, it's not working.

```
table.component.html
 <p>{{'company' | translate}}</p>  - this value is changing
 <p>{{payment.amount | mycurrency}}</p> - this value is not changing



mycurrency.ts

import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { formatCurrency, getCurrencySymbol } from '@angular/common';
import { DEFAULT_LANGUAGE } from '@ngx-translate/core';
@Pipe({
    name: 'mycurrency',
})
export class MycurrencyPipe implements PipeTransform {
    code: any;
    constructor() {
        if (localStorage.getItem("language") == 'fr' || localStorage.getItem("language") == 'de') {
            this.code='EUR';
        }
        else {
            this.code ='USD';
        }
    }

    transform(
        value: number,
        currencyCode: string = this.code,
        display:
            | 'code'
            | 'symbol'
            | 'symbol-narrow'
            | string
            | boolean = 'symbol',
        digitsInfo: string = '3.2-2',
        locale: string = localStorage.getItem("language"),
    ): string | null {
        console.log("Ds");
        return formatCurrency(
            value,
            locale,
            getCurrencySymbol(currencyCode, 'wide'),
            currencyCode,
            digitsInfo,
        );
    }
}
'''
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [getCurrencySymbol](https://angular.io/api/common/getCurrencySymbol). Check this example for more.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-currency-symbol-pipe-9pvmdc

Answer (score 1):

You can use the angular currency pipe

`table.component.html`

```
<p>
    {{payment.amount | currency:currencyCode}}
</p>
```

`currencyCode` can be the variable containing the standard currency code('USD', 'EURO', 'INR' etc), or you can assign this from your dropdown.

Check the below example

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rj7e4t

Comment: ok. But currencyCode value is not changing when the language switch happens.  When I change language than <th>{{'company' | translate}}</th>, company value change but the currency is not changing.

Comment: can you share your language switch dropdown?

Comment: The Problem here is that the Symbol is on the Left side, but it should be on the right side